# Convert key-value array back into normal array with Object.fromEntries()

Tags: javascript

Let's suggest I have an array:

```
const arr = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

And `Object.entries(arr)` returns the following: `[[0, '1'], [1, '2'], [2, '3'], [3, '4']]`.
How to convert it back to a normal array? That is:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Because `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(arr))` returns `{0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3', 3: '4'}` -- not what I expected.

UPD
Do not accept answers like `Object.values(obj)` because sometimes I need a normal key-value object from `Object.fromEntries()`

Comment: "*Because Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(arr)) returns {0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3', 3: '4'} -- not what I expected.*" it's an object which is built up from the entries provided. There is no way for the JS runtime that you didn't want plain object but some other one.

Answer (score 1):

You could map

```js
const arr = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
const entries = Object.entries(arr)
console.log(entries)
console.log(entries.map(item => item[1]))
// or
console.log(entries.map(([key,val]) => val))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the second index of each nested array:

```js
const arr = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
const rra = Object.entries(arr);

const original = rra.map(i => i[1]);

console.log(original);
```